# Crystal Script condition statement 'This field name is not known' error

Tags: crystal-reports

this is my current condition statement

```
IF {AR_DEBIT.InvoiceNo} = "" THEN {AR_DEBIT.Description}
ELSE {AR_DEBIT.Description} & "(" & {AR_DEBIT.InvoiceNo} & " - " & ToText({AR_DEBIT.InvoiceDate}, "dd-MMM-yyyy") & ")"
```

not working...prompt error `IF {AR_DEBIT.InvoiceNo} = "" THEN this field is not known` bla bla something like that...

when i remove the condition,

```
{AR_DEBIT.Description} & "(" & {AR_DEBIT.InvoiceNo} & " - " & ToText({AR_DEBIT.InvoiceDate}, "dd-MMM-yyyy") & ")"
```

the report show no error...anybody?

Comment: Try this..

IF IsNull({AR_DEBIT.InvoiceNo}) or {AR_DEBIT.InvoiceNo} = ""

Comment: First check if invoiceno field exist in database